# Making a sentence negative

Tags: negation

I've seen the following negative sentences in an English book. Placing a negative auxiliary before the first verb seems to be the right way:

- ***I don't think*** she'll pass the exam.
- The baby's tired. ***I don't think*** he's going to wake up tonight.

My question is, would it be grammatically acceptable to say:

- I think ***she won't pass*** the exam. *or*
- The baby's tired. I think ***he isn't going to wake up*** tonight.

Comment: For most purposes, *I don't think [X]* and *I think [NOT X]* are equivalent in meaning. But there are probably contexts where one version carries significant implications / overtones that the other doesn't.

Comment: @ FumbleFinger: Thanks for your comment. I wonder why the other option (I think she won't pass the exam) has been marked WRONG in the answer key!

Comment: I think I will keep my thoughts to myself. I don't think I will keep my thoughts to myself. Clearly,the emphasis is different.

Comment: M.N.: You'll have to ask Lambie exactly what "emphasis" is different in his/her example. Apart from the obvious fact that the two statements as given are complete opposites (in #1, *I will stay silent*, in #2 *I will speak out)*, and the fact that native speakers wouldn't often say *I think I will **not** keep my thoughts to myself,* I don't really see any difference in whether you negate the verb ***think*** as opposed to negating the statement that you think isn't true / won't happen. But as I said, there may be clear-cut examples where *what I think is untrue / what I don't think is true.*

Comment: FumbleFinger: Thanks very much. You've been a great help. +1

Comment: @Lambie: Thanks a lot for your comment. Could you please explain the difference between the two examples you've given?

Comment: One is attributing a negative form to the verb think and the other isn't. This could have implications in logic. One is what you think and the other is what you don't think.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think she passes most of her exams. General statement, simple present.

A general statement about a future exam:

I think she won't pass the exam. = I don't think she will pass the exam.

It depends on whether you want the emphasis on what you think or the fact of her passing or not passing the exam. Your choice.

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote there. Perhaps "general statement" should be teased out a bit.   "She hasn't been doing well at school. I don't think she passes most of her exams."